# How to use Liquibase contexts with Jooq code generation

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase, jooq

I have a Springboot project that uses Liquibase for database migration and Jooq for database access and the associated code generation. This works fine when Jooq introspects a database that has all the changes applied, but now I wanted to transition to an in-memory H2 database for the code generation so that Jooq is not dependent on my actual (Postgres) database.

But when generating sources with Jooq I get an error now, for a duplicate key exception on a column where I have a unique constraint. I noticed that is because I am using Liquibase contexts in order to insert different data in test, dev and production environments. Jooq seems to ignore these contexts though and applies all changes to same database, and when I insert the same data in test and dev the generation fails. So how can I ensure that Jooq and Liquibase use the correct context (and maven profile) already at the generate sources stage?

Some excerpts from my setup:

pom.xml

```
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>local</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>

...

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
                <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
                <version>${jooq.version}</version>

                <!-- The plugin should hook into the generate goal -->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <!-- Specify the plugin configuration.
                     The configuration format is the same as for the standalone code generator -->
                <configuration>
                <generator>
                    <database>
                        <name>org.jooq.meta.extensions.liquibase.LiquibaseDatabase</name>
                        <properties>
                            <property>
                                <key>sort</key>
                                <value>liquibase</value>
                            </property>
                            <property>
                                <key>scripts</key>
                                <value>src/main/resources/liquibase/changelog-master.xml</value>
                            </property>
                            <property>
                                <key>unqualifiedSchema</key>
                                <value>none</value>
                            </property>
                            <property>
                                <key>defaultNameCase</key>
                                <value>lower</value>
                            </property>
                        </properties>
                    </database>
                    <target>
                        <packageName>com.graphite.horses</packageName>
                        <directory>target/generated-sources/jooq</directory>
                    </target>
                    <generate>
                        <javaTimeTypes>true</javaTimeTypes>
                    </generate>
                </generator>
                </configuration>
            </plugin
```

Liquibase change file:

```
    <changeSet id="addInitialCredentialsValuesLocal" author="daniel" context="local">
        <insert tableName="credentials">
            <column name="key" value="my-token"/>
            <column name="platform" value="web"/>
        </insert>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="addInitialCredentialsValuesTest" author="daniel" context="test">
        <insert tableName="credentials">
            <column name="key" value="my-token"/>
            <column name="platform" value="web"/>
        </insert>
    </changeSet>
```

And this is where it fails since "my-token" is inserted again in the Jooq's in-memory database even though the test context should not be active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from jOOQ 3.14.0 and 3.13.2 (see [#9872](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9872)), the "contexts" parameter can be passed along to the Liquibase `Database` instance  like this:

```xml
<!-- The property "changeLogParameters.contexts" will be passed on to the 
     liquibase.database.Database.update() call (jOOQ 3.13.2+).
     See https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/contexts.html -->
<property>
  <key>changeLogParameters.contexts</key>
  <value>!test</value>
</property>
```

See also the example configuration here:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-liquibase/